# Codeigniter Image upload using jquery and ajax error

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, file, upload

I need guidance for following Query.
I am Trying to upload a file or move a file to the desired directory, But It's get failed. On the form, all the other fields data passed to controller except input['file'] data.

Please go through the following code.


**View :**

Form is displayed using Bootstrap Modal only minimal code is posted

```
<form method="post" action="<?php //echo base_url().'admin/students/update_accomodation'; ?>" id="accform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>Students</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" name="student" value="" />
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>Room</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" name="room" value="" />
                    </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>Stay</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select name="stay" class="form-control" id="stay">
                            <option value="1">1 Month</option>
                            <option value="2">2 Month</option>
                            <option value="3">3 Month</option>
                            <option value="4">4 Month</option>
                            <option value="5">5 Month</option>
                            <option value="6">6 Month</option>
                            <option value="7">7 Month</option>
                            <option value="8">8 Month</option>
                            <option value="9">9 Month</option>
                            <option value="10">10 Month</option>
                            <option value="11">11 Month</option>
                            <option value="12">12 Month</option>
                            <option value="18">18 Month</option>
                            <option value="24">24 Month</option>
                            <option value="36">36 Month</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>Upload PDF</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="btn btn-default btn-file" />
                    </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary accomodation">Submit</button>
  </div>
    </form>
```

**Ajax**

Is on same page and in footer, jquery.js file is loading pefectly, and other than file field data is also passed to controller.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $(".accomodation").click(function(event)  {
        event.preventDefault();
        //var formData = $('#accform').serialize();
       // var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        //var formData = $('#accform').formSerialize();
        //console.log(formData);
        //alert(JSON.stringify(formData));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/students/update_accomodation'); ?>",
            data: $('#accform').serialize(),
            //data: new FormData($("#accform")[0]),
            processData: false,
            success: function(res)  {
                //var json = JSON.parse(res);
                var parsed = res;
                console.log(parsed);
                if(parsed.status_code == 1) {
                    alert('data inserted successfully');
                    window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('admin/bookings'); ?>";
                }else {
                    alert(parsed.status);
                }
            }

        });
    });       
});
```

**Controller**

```
function update_accomodation()  {
    //form input validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('student_id','Student ID','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('room_id','Room ID','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('stay','stay','required');
    if (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {                        //check file is selected
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('file','File','required');
    }
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)  {               //form validation false
        $data = array(
            'status' => validation_errors(),
            'status_code' => 2
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }   else    {          
        //echo json_encode(array('data' => $_FILES['file']['name']));
        //form validation true
        if (0 < $_FILES['file']['error']) {
            $data = array(
                'status' => 'File uploading error',
                'status_code' => 3
            );
            echo json_encode($data);
    }   else    {
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //filename="file" 
            $targetPath = "uploads/students/contracts/".rand(0,10000).$_FILES['file']['name'];      //targetpath with random number as prefix
            move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath);                                //move file to target folder
            $data1 = array(                                             //take inputs
                'stay' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                'id_upload' => $targetPath
            );
            $data = array(
                'status' => 'upload successfully',
                'status_code' => 1
            );
            echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
}
```

**What Errors I am Getting :**

1) input['file'] value is not get passed, only  input['text'] and other value get passed.

2) Form validation error for input['file'](offcourse because file value not get passed).

**What I have done so far :**
1)I tried Multiple types to accept form data, I comment it in ajax.

2)I tried jquery.form.min.js plugin(link : http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). after using this plugin the input['file'] value can get acceptet(traced in console) but not passed to controller, getting error undefined variable: file.

3) ProcessData: false, contentType: false, is also used.

4) enctype="multipart/form-data" is also included.

**Final Thing to mention**
 The above code working perfectly on another controller and view in existing project, I copied same code but it won't work on current controller. Need Help, Thank you.

**Updated AJAX code suggested by User** : but it won't work for me, as null values get passed to controller

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $(".accomodation").click(function(e)  {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/students/update_accomodation'); ?>",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(res)  {
                console.log(res);
            }

        });
    });       
});
```

**Acceptance of answer with correction**
Following answer work for me, Thank you so much.

```
var form = $('#accform');
var formData = new FormData(form[0]);
```

Instead

```
var formData = new FormData(this);
```

Comment: @ADyson : Hi, I already checked above solution, but it won't work for me, any other suggestion after looking into the code, because above code is working on another controller and view. Thank you.

Comment: why doesn't it work for you, exactly? It clearly works for a lot of other people judging by the number of upvotes and its "protected" status. Have you got some special extra circumstance which makes your question different? I fail to see how the controller and view has any impact, that's just changing the URL - how does that make any difference to the process, in your opinion?

Comment: In your code above, you have forgotten to set the contentType option, which is the most obvious mistake, there may be others, but you should start there.

Comment: @ADyson : I don't know why it is not working for me, That's why I paste all of my code, if you can see I have mentioned that I tried processData: false and other things, do you think is there any other files impact on code like jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.serialize() cannot accept to upload files using Jquery & Axaj.

To achieve this use

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.accomodation').on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data:formData,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(data){
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }));
  }));
```

Comment: Hi, I also tried this code earlier, not working, Now getting validation required error for all the fields, it means all form fields data not get passed to controller, can you please give suggestion on this, Thank you.

Comment: I also updated question with your suggestion, please check if anything wrong, Thank you.

Comment: What the errors you are facing?

Comment: In console I can see nothing is passed, I mean call is going properly to controller, but nothing is get passed {"fields":[]}

Comment: use - >  data:formData,

Comment: And check in your controller print_r($_FILES); exit;

Comment: Yup, I do same, also after var formData = new FormData(this); is tried to print data in console.log(formData); but 'FormData {}' is null.

Comment: In controller I return json_encode() all $_POST but It also display null in console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157273/discussion-between-siddhartha-esunuri-and-pra5hant).